# Should a splash page linking to other multisite instances also be a multisite instance or a bare HTML page?

Tags: 8, multi-sites

**This is the situation:**

1. Global domain: www.domain.com (exists of one page, with links to other 3 subdomains)
2. Sub domain 1: sub1.domain.com (full website)
3. Sub domain 2: sub2.domain.com (full website)
4. Sub domain 3: sub3.domain.com (full website)

**My question:**

Is it overkill to also create a site for the global domain? It will only have one page (frontpage). Or what is the best practice to accomplish this? **The global domain is just a landingpage where you can make a choice between the 3 subsites.**

Comment: That's an opinion, it totally depends on how complex this landing page will be, who is supposed to change its content, and so on. Maybe have a bare HTML splash page and before it gets too complex add another multisite instance for the splash page.

Comment: If it is not to complex and it does not require much resources (server), I would use a site instead of just a HTML splash page ... ?

Comment: I'd agree. More flexible on the long run. But yeah, it depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need **more flexibility** on the long run, you better **create a separate website for the global domain**. Keep in mind that it will **require extra resources** on your server.

If your **global landing page is simple** you can consider the option to only **use a HTML page**. Keep in mind that this will **give you less options on the long run**.